# How to extract text from JSON response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-api

I am trying to make url shortener that uses goo.gl API. But i stucked when I have to get short URL from JSON response!

**After entering this code in Chrome Console:**

```
var longURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
$.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: '{ longUrl: "' + longURL +'"}',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(response); 
                }
            });
```

**I get following ouptut:**
[image]

I see that my short URL is in `resoinseText.id`. How to extract it from there?

Comment: Since you specified `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery parses it automatically. You shouldn't call `JSON.parse()` yourself.

Comment: On the other hand, you should use `JSON.stringify()` when creating the data, instead of trying to construct the JSON by hand.

Comment: @Barmar, so, how to get a variable with my short URL?

Comment: @Barmar `console.log(result);` prints `false`

Comment: Are you doing that in the console or in the `success` function? The `response` variable is local to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `JSON.parse()`, because jQuery does that automatically when you specify `dataType: 'json'`. The value you want will then be in the `id` property of `response`.

```
var longURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: '{ longUrl: "' + longURL +'"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: here you are:) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988320/error-while-adding-json-responses-to-an-array)