# Error while adding JSON responses to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to make a url shortener using goog.gl api. Thanks to @Barmar now I can get my short URL using this code:

```
var shortURL;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{ longUrl: "' + longURL +'"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            shortURL = response.id;
        }
    });
```

But I want to shorten an array of links! So I decided to use loop.

I created longURL[] and shortURL[] but if I run this code I get such output in shortURL array: `[undefined × 10, "http://goo.gl/AxzWLx"];` Full code:

```
    var longURL = [];//there are some urls
var shortURL = [];
for (var k = 0; k < longURL.length; k++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{ longUrl: "' + longURL[k] +'"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            shortURL[k] = response.id;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all your callback functions share the same value of `k`, because it's not a per-function closure variable. You can use the `context:` option to pass the appropriate value to each callback.

```
var longURL = [];//there are some urls
var shortURL = [];
for (var k = 0; k < longURL.length; k++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{ longUrl: "' + longURL[k] +'"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: k,
        success: function(response) {
            shortURL[this] = response.id;
        }
    });
}
```

Another solution is to use `$.each()`. Since each iteration is a function call, you'll close over the parameters:

```
var longURL = [];//there are some urls
var shortURL = [];
$.each(longURL, function(k, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{ longUrl: "' + url +'"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            shortURL[k] = response.id;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Second variant works fine and looks more pretty and logical for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic JavaScript problem.  In your `success` function, you are using the same `k` for each AJAX call.  You need to capture the value of `k` for each iteration.

```
var longURL = [];//there are some urls
var shortURL = [];
for (var k = 0; k < longURL.length; k++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS&key=AIzaSyANFw1rVq_vnIzT4vVOwIw3fF1qHXV7Mjw',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: '{ longUrl: "' + longURL[k] +'"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: {key: k}, // the "this" value in the callback
        success: function(response) {
            shortURL[this.key] = response.id;
        }
    });
}
```